# Issue with Kubespray Overwriting Sysbox Modifications in kubelet.service

Tags: kubernetes

### Description

I'm encountering a challenge during the deployment of a Kubernetes cluster (v1.28.6) using Kubespray (release-2.24) while integrating Sysbox. The Sysbox integration was performed with the following commands:

```bash
kubectl label nodes node1 sysbox-install=yes
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nestybox/sysbox/master/sysbox-k8s-manifests/sysbox-install.yaml
```

Initially, the journalctl -eu kubelet-config-helper reported a No Kubelet systemd file could be identified for exec-line error, which I addressed by modifying the /usr/local/bin/kubelet-config-helper.sh script, specifically hardcoding the kubelet.service path.

However, a new issue has surfaced. The Sysbox installation process modifies the kubelet.service file by adding $KUBELET_CRIO_ARGS. Upon rerunning the Kubespray playbook, the modifications made by Sysbox are overwritten, resulting in Sysbox being unavailable for pods, leading to failures.

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Deploy Kubernetes cluster using Kubespray.
2. Integrate Sysbox using the provided commands.
3. Observe the addition of $KUBELET_CRIO_ARGS in the kubelet.service file during Sysbox installation.
4. Rerun Kubespray playbook, causing the removal of Sysbox modifications.

### Expected Behavior

I anticipate that the Kubespray playbook should refrain from overwriting or removing the adjustments made by Sysbox during its installation, ensuring the continuous availability of Sysbox for pod usage.

### Additional Information

- Kubernetes Version: v1.28.6
- Kubespray Version: release-2.24
- One node cluster

I appreciate any insights or recommendations on preventing the Kubespray playbook from undoing the modifications made by the Sysbox installation.